# RewriteRule in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a newbie in Apache and I'm trying to shorten the URL of my pages, from

```
http://mysrvr:9191/my/long/path/to/app.php
```

to

```
http://mysrvr:9191/app.php
```

I thought it could be done with **RewriteRule** in an .htaccess file, but it didn't work at all, so I tried with a very simple test. 
This one doesn't work either.

I will talk about this test.

This is **.htaccess** in my application folder:

```
DirectoryIndex robbie.html index4.html 
Options +FollowSymLinks
#Edited --- RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index4.html$ $1/robbie.html
```

I tried also

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index4.html$ /$1/robbie.html
```

But when introduced

```
http://mysrvr:9191/my/long/path/to/index4.html
```

none of them two options redirected to

```
http://mysrvr:9191/my/long/path/to/robbie.html
```

**DirectoryIndex**, however, works as expected so I discard the idea of .htaccess being ignored.

This made me think that perhaps **mod_rewrite** wasn't uploaded but:

```
> httpd.exe -t -D DUMP_MODULES
[Wed Aug 20 12:04:15 2014] [error] (OS 11004)The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.  : Could not resolve host name hserver.rob.igroup -- ignoring!
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 win32_module (static)
 mpm_winnt_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 asis_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_default_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_default_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 isapi_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Would anyone please share their ideas on this issue?

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: See here where it mentions this point from @hjpotter92 (default is off) - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm sorry but as I pasted avoiding commented lines I missed to include "RewriteEngine On". I'm editing right now.

Comment: @hjpotter92, as I said "RewriteEngine On" was actually in .htaccess, although I forgot to write it down in my original question - subsaned after edition. Even with that instruction, there was no redirection taking place.